# How do I show an array in reverse in a template using *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I need to show the list of an array from last to first.

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let user of _users.reverse(); let i = index">
  <tr>
      <td>{{ _users[i].firstName }} {{ _users[i].lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

But this shows an error in console. But it still works ! It should've been a warning though since the template is rendering.

`ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'John'. Current value: 'Tim'. Angular 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can create custom pipes for make reverse array**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'reverse' })

export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    return value.slice().reverse();
  }
}


<ng-container *ngFor="let user of _users | reverse; let i = index">
  <tr>
      <td>{{ _users[i].firstName }} {{ _users[i].lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Probably the most elegant solution! Clean and reusable.